# How can I apply a or/and operation to all element in a python list with efficiency

Tags: python

I know that reduce and all/any can do the trick, but its performance is bad when the list is large.

For example:

Define a function including print to check whether the function has been executed

```
In [33]: def func(x):
   ....:     print x
   ....:     return bool(x)
   ....:
```

Pass `operator.or_` as the reduce function

```
In [34]: import operator
In [35]: reduce(operator.or_, [func(1), func(0)])
1
0
Out[35]: True
```

Then we found that the second function has been executed even that the first function returns True.

If I use or operation directly, it will return immediately once it find that one of them return True.

```
In [36]: func(1) or func(0)
1
Out[36]: True
```

However, I can't do so if I have a large list.

Is there any elegant way to do that? Or I should what a for loop to check?

## Update

The origin way I use for any is

```
In [26]: any([func(1), func(0)])
1
0
Out[26]: True
```

It did evaluate all the function.

Via @Martijn Pieters' answer, I now know that I might use it in the wrong way. Sorry for the unclearing.

Comment: Doesn't `any` short circuit?

Comment: `any()` doesn't have bad performance, it's what you want here.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to compare adjacent values in a list?

Comment: You are passing in an already created list to `any()`; that is indeed inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any()` is *exactly* what you need here, combined with a generator expression:

```
any(func(i) for i in big_list)
```

This will *stop* iterating for the first value where `func(i)` returns a true value. As soon as a `True` value is found, you've proven that there is *a* value that is true in the input sequence ("is there *any* value that is true?" -> yup, we found at least one).

For `and`, you'd use `all()` instead:

```
all(func(i) for i in big_list)
```

which will return `False` the moment a `func(i)` falsey value is found. If *one* false value is found, then you have proven that there is at least *one* value that is not true, so they cannot all be true.

Note that these two functions are given a generator expression:

```
(func(i) for i in big_list)
```

This is evaluated lazily; every time you ask for the next value of a generator expression, it'll evaluate the loop and execute the `func(i)` expression once. It will not produce the whole list at once, it'll produce items *one by one*.

Your `reduce(operator.or_, [func(1), func(0)])` expression *has* to build the whole input list before it can call `reduce()`. The `reduce()` method will process the *whole* input list, it will not short-circuit, because it has no knowledge of what operation is being applied to the input values. You could give `reduce()` a generator expression as well, but it won't stop iterating once the outcome is set (on the first true value for `or` or the first false value for `and`), again because `reduce()` has no specialist knowledge of the operation being performed.

Comment: You should probably mention the difference between creating a list, which executes func() for every list item, and creating an iterator that will only execute func() for the elements that are accessed.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm wondering why `any(func(i) for i in big_list)` and `any(big_list)` have different behavior.

Comment: @waitingkuo: The same reason that `and` and `or` have different behaviour; they are different operations.

Comment: @waitingkuo `func(i) for i in big_list` evaluates to an _iterator_, not a list.  `any` and `all` only go through an iterator as far as they have too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you, I know how they work now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answer, the problem with this:

```
reduce(operator.or_, [func(1), func(0)])
```

Is that the arguments are *always* evaluated before a function gets called, since Python doesn't do [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Using an iterator (like in Martijn's answer) avoids this, since it generates the list as needed instead of all at once.